will original subdivision covenants apply
If an undeveloped tract of land located in a subdivision is later developed into a new separate subdivision with its own covenants, do the original covenants apply?

What does the deed say?

The original covenants apply unless and until they are vacated, either as provided in the instrument establishing the covenants, or as provided other applicable law (in the U.S., generally, state real estate law).
One exception to this is that racially restrictive covenants are void as a matter of law without any action being taken by anyone.

Could the covenants be combined if there's no conflicts? E.g. the original covenants have X, the new covenants have Y, so they effectively have X and Y on the new subdivision?

@barmar Yes. That is the default rule.
